# Show convergence but ...

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, ratio

I have to show that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}({\frac{1}{2}})^n+({\frac{1}{3}})^n$ is convergent. First I thought I could use the ratio test but the sum start from n=0 and not n=1. How can I then show the convergent?

Comment: Since both the terms inside the summation are positive, you can separate the sum into two.

Comment: Yes, the sum starts at $n=0$. And… ?

Comment: So it is not a problem using the ratio test if the sum starts in n=0?

Comment: @Lifeni No, it is not.

Answer (score 2):

If two series converges their sum converges $(<\infty$ is sign  for convergence )
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n < \infty , \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n < \infty \implies \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n+b_n) < \infty. $$

Can you prove it?

Comment: Nice, but is it not $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$$ and $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n$$

Comment: @Lifeni Convergence doesn't matter on first finite number of terms . Can you see why ?

Comment: Yes it make sense. So I just have to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}({\frac{1}{2}})^n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}({\frac{1}{3}})^n$ are convergent (for example with the ratio test), and then use your theorem?

Comment: yes :) that will do.

Comment: Thank you a lot

Comment: @Lifeni Also It is completely fine if start your ratio test from $0$ itself. It's just for a convention that they start with $n=1$

Comment: Thank you, it make sense. I t also applies that: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n < \infty , \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n < \infty \implies \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n-b_n) < \infty. $$?

Comment: yes it does. You can start index from $0$ as well if your sequence is defined at $0$

Answer (score 1):

One more answer:

$a_n:=(1/2)^n+(1/3)^n\le$

$ (1/2)^n +(1/2)^n =2(1/2)^n=:b_n$;

$\sum_{0}^{n}a_n$ converges (Comparison test).